# Android ActivityThread error

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I cannot figure out what is causing this Thread error. Here is my code. I commented out almost all the code and it still won't work:

```
package com.dd.relay;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.dd.relay.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             // We'll define a custom screen layout here (the one shown above), but
             // typically, you could just use the standard ListActivity layout.
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             //ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.relaylist);

          // Make a GET request for data
            /* String url = "http://localhost.com/contacts";
             String res = null;
             try {
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.execute(new URL(url));

                Log.v(EXTRA_MESSAGE, res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             // Now create a new list adapter bound to the cursor.
             // SimpleListAdapter is designed for binding to a Cursor.
             String[] from = new String[] {"First", "Last", "Number"};
             int[] to = new int[] {R.id.first, R.id.last, R.id.number};


            // Create list for contacts
             List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
             Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();

             int id = 0;
             while(id<10)
             {
             RelayContact contact = new RelayContact("Matt", "Hintzke", "2062259311", id);
             temp.put("First",contact.first);
             temp.put("Last", contact.last);
             temp.put("Number", contact.num);

             data.add(temp);
             id++;
             }



             ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list, from, to);  // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those columns.

             // Bind to our new adapter.

             lv.setAdapter(adapter);
             */
            // CharSequence msg = "List loaded";
            // Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
             //Toast mytoast = Toast.makeText(context,  msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             //mytoast.show();
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




}
```

And here is the error from the console

```
[2013-07-20 19:18:36 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.launchInBackground(DebugUIPlugin.java:1286)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.launch(DebugUITools.java:753)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.debugRunningApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:176)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1733)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:912)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:591)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:868)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleWAIT(HandleWait.java:88)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleChunk(HandleWait.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Comment: That seems to be an Eclipse-generated stack trace and not an Android app's stack trace. Is your app actually crashing or can you not debug using the ADT plugin? Does the above error occur on other apps?

Comment: yes it is crashing.. and haven't tested on other apps. about to now

Comment: and no, just created a brand new Android App and it was fine

Comment: yes it seems to be from Eclipse side, have you tried to clean the project ?

Comment: Alot of people seemed to be getting this..It's logged as a bug...https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388463 . Have you tried creating a seperate UI thread to call this and see if it's still an error?